# Sending JSON object via AJAX to PHP throws XML read error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I've seen a lot of questions about this topic but I don't have find any answer for my question.

I'm making a website with a form where one will registrer a student and send it as a JSON object to a php script via AJAX but whatever reason it doesn't enter to the ajax part.

this is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='es'>
<!-- Cabecera -->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Página de registro de alumnos</title>
    <!-- CSS, tanto del bootstrap principal como el custom en general -->
    <link href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prueba.css">

</head>
<!-- cuerpo en general -->
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Front-End Test</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Registo</a></li>
        <li><a href="consulta.html">Consulta</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
    <!-- descripción general -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>REGISTRO DE ALUMNOS</h1>
        <p>Por favor, rellene el siguiente formulario para el registro de alumnos</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- la parte del formato del formulario -->

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form enctype='application/json' name="alumno" id="alumno">
            <h2>Nombre:</h2>
            <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"> </input>
            <h2>Apellido Paterno:</h2>
            <input type="text" id="ap_pat" name="ap_pat"> </input>
            <h2>Apellido Materno:</h2>
            <input type="text" id="ap_mat" name="ap_mat"> </input>
            <h2>Carrera:</h2>
            <select id="carrera" name="carrera">
                <option selected value="1">SISTEMAS COMPUTACIONALES</option>
                <option value="2">QUIMICA</option>
                <option value="3">MECATRONICA</option>
                <option value="4">ELECTRONICA</option>
                <option value="5">ELECTROMECANICA</option>
                <option value="6">INDUSTRIAL</option>
                <option value="7">LOGISTICA</option>
                <option value="8">GESTION EMPRESARIAL</option>
                <option value="9">TICS</option>
                <option value="10">MAESTRIA EN CIENCIAS DE LA INGENIERIA</option>
                <option value="11">MAESTRIA EN CIENCIAS DE LA INGENIERIA AMBIENTAL</option>
                <option value="12">DOCTORADO EN CIENCIAS AMBIENTALES</option>
            </select>
            <h2>Genero:</h2>
            <input type="checkbox" id="genero" name="genero"> <label for="genero">Haz click en el recuadro si es hombre</label> </input>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="loader">
</div>

<div class="container">
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button" id="boton">Registrar alumno &raquo;</a></p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./registroscript.js">   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my javascipt registroscript.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#boton").click(function(){
    //validaciones
    var specialChars = "<>@!#$%^&*()_+[]{}?:;|'\"\\,./~`-=1234567890¬°~`¨¡¿´¨"
    var check = function(string){
        if(string.length > 0){
            for(i = 0; i < specialChars.length;i++){
                if(string.indexOf(specialChars[i]) > -1){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            alert("Por favor, rellene todos los campos");
            return true;
        }
    }

    if(!check($('#nombre').val()) && !check($('#ap_pat').val()) && !check($('#ap_mat').val())){ 
        //ajax
        var formData = JSON.stringify($("#alumno").serializeArray());
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "inline";
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "alumnos.php",
            data: $("#alumno").serialize(),
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"json",    
        })
        .done(function (json) {
            alert("El alumno ha sido agregado");
        })
        //en caso de fallo
        .fail(function(xhr, status, errorThrown){
            alert( "Ha ocurrido un problema al momento de enviar el pedido" );
        })
        .always(function(xhr, status){
            document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
        });
    } else {
        alert("no se pudo enviar el pedido");
    }
});
});
```

and finally this is the php script i was using for testing

```
<?php   
$usuario = $_POST['nombre'];
$ap_pat = $_POST['ap_pat'];
$ap_mat = $_POST['ap_mat'];
$carrera = $_POST['carrera'];
$genero = $_POST['genero'];

$file = fopen('alumno.json','w+');

echo "1: ".$usuario; 
echo "2: ".$ap_pat;
echo "3: ".$ap_mat;
echo "4: ".$carrera;
echo "5: ".$genero;
?>
```

When I try to run the ajax part,in the firefox's console "TypeError: $.ajax(...).done is not a function

Error de lectura XML: no se encuentra el elemento
Ubicación: file:///D:/Proyectos/ITT/Examen%20Front-End/alumnos.php
Número de línea 15, columna 3"

EDIT:
the JQuery was in fact an older version that didn't support .done in ajax and corrected the double JQuery source

And it seems the main problem is in the php code

Comment: I'm not sure... But try to remove the trailing coma at the end of `dataType:"json", `.

Comment: Why are you loading two jquery libraries? Use one, and move it to the <head> your calling jquery objects without loading the library first.

Comment: It looks like you include jQuery twice, and the second one included is only v1.4.3. The jqXHR object returned by `$.ajax()` did not start supporting `.done()` until v1.5.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are missing a semi-colon:

```
var specialChars = "<>@!#$%^&*()_+[]{}?:;|'\"\\,./~`-=1234567890¬°~`¨¡¿´¨";
```

Try fixing syntax errors first.

Comment: In reality there's in fact the semi-colon right there, and the firefox's console doesn't mark any others syntax errors